# Ionic - Upload file to local

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, ng-file-upload

I am working on a Ionic Android application, and I am trying to upload file to the local storage. I don't know what is the best way to do that, and how can I know the path to the application folder (is it the same on every android device ?).

I tried to use `ng-file-upload`, but it only offers to upload a file to a server, not locally.

Thanks for you help.

Comment: you want to write to the device file system ?

Comment: Use the file plugin found on ngCordova site.

Comment: @reviloera I'd like to write on the application folder.

Comment: @t0mm13b I looking about the ngCordova plugin file. I'll keep you informed, thanks.